# Chessboard combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

A white square and a black square have to be chosen on a chessboard such that they do not lie in the same row or column or diagonal.  In how many ways can they be chosen.

**My approach:-**

Ways of choosing 1 white square =32c1

Ways of choosing a black square such that it is not in same row, column or diagonal would be (32-(4+4))=24c1

now answer should be (32c1 * 24c1)/2 = 768/2 = 384 --->Reason for dividing by 2 is that while doing
32c1 * 24c1 we have done ordering like suppose a white square chosen was e4 and the black square
chosen was g5
so while doing 32c1 * 24c1..

I have counted cases of e4 g5 and g5 e4 as separate, hence need to adjust that overcounting.

But according to the answer given in the book, its 768 only

Comment: @coffeemath A white square and a black square can't be on the same diagonal.

Comment: You chose a white square first and then a black one. So the sequence g5 e4 would not occur.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I removed my comment since you are right it was irrelevant.

Comment: First choice is 64, second choice 24. Since you count solutions double this way, the answer is 64 * 24 / 2 = 768. It seems the solution in the book is correct.